# How to use iface.actionVertexTool() in a pyqgis plugin with custom QgsMapCanvas?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgis, pyqgis

I need to edit features in my pyqgis plugin's `QgsMapCanvas` instantiated as `self.canvas` . I have enabled snapping options and triggered vertex tool via python code, but other than the cursor changing to `CrossCursor`, nothing happens when it hovers over the layer to be edited on the custom `QgsMapCanvas` . There is no `QgsActionVertexTool` which is similar to `QgsActionPan`. I feel that `iface.actionVertexTool()` might not be suitable because that might be only for the `QgisInterface()`, but am open for corrections.

Here is the code.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsSnappingConfig, QgsTolerance, QgsMapLayer
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool
from qgis.utils import iface

from .feedback import Feedback

class GeoManipulation():
    def __init__(self, canvas, project, view, console, button):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.project = project
        self.view = view
        self.console_out = console
        self.gm_edit_button = button
        self.setSnapConfig()
        self.vertexEditor()
        
    def setSnapConfig(self):
        snap_config = QgsSnappingConfig()

        snap_config.setEnabled(True)
        snap_config.setMode(snap_config.SnappingMode.AllLayers)
        snap_config.setType(snap_config.Vertex)
        snap_config.setTolerance(12)
        snap_config.setUnits(QgsTolerance.Pixels)

        snap_config.setIntersectionSnapping(True)
        snap_config.setSelfSnapping(True)

        self.project.setTopologicalEditing(True)
        self.project.setSnappingConfig(snap_config)
        
    def vertexEditor(self):
        self.cur_lyr = self.view.currentLayer()
        
        vertex_action = iface.actionVertexTool()
        vertex_tool = QgsMapTool(self.canvas)
        vertex_tool.setAction(vertex_action)
        self.canvas.setMapTool(vertex_tool)
        
        if self.gm_edit_button.isChecked():
            if self.cur_lyr == None or self.cur_lyr.type() != QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
                Feedback().error(self.console_out, "Please Select an Asset Layer")
                self.gm_edit_button.setChecked(False)
            else:
                print(self.cur_lyr)
                self.cur_lyr.startEditing()
                # vertex_action.trigger()
                vertex_tool.activate()
                
        else:
            Feedback().success(self.console_out, "Edits to Current Layer Successfully Saved")
            self.cur_lyr.commitChanges()
            vertex_tool.deactivate()
```

I also tried with `QgsMapToolEdit`, but it did not work.